# How to stop video from being downloaded on mobile

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, html5-video, autoplay

I have a site with multiple case studies that have video headers which are set to autoplay.  These videos are contained within a parent div, which is hidden on mobile and tablet.  Since the videos will never be seen on mobile, is there a way I can get the browser not to download the video?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent video from pre-loading on website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766639/prevent-video-from-pre-loading-on-website)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, load the video dynamically with javascript IF the client/device/screen is of the width you wish. In this example: jQuery.

```
if($(window).width() > 500) {
    loadvideo();
}

function loadvideo() {
   $video = something;
   $(".parent").child().val($video);
}
```